# how to run update statement by connecting mysql from os prompt?

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to run a mysql query to update a single record in all my servers

It is having special characters like ? as below

mysql --user=test_user --password=xxxxx  local_gw -sN -e 'UPDATE SER_MET SET VALUE='0 0 0 1 1 ? 2099' WHERE GROUP = 'TEST';commit'

Got the below output:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.61, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: getting error message as its optionsmysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.48, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?

Comment: would you add exact error message to the question ? also try escaping `?` with `\?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
mysql --user=test_user --password=xxxx  local_gw -sN -e 'UPDATE SER_MET SET VALUE='\''0 0 0 1 1 ? 2099'\'' WHERE `GROUP`= "TEST";commit'
```

Answer (score 2):

mysql -u user -p -e 'Your SQL Query Here' database-name

OR

mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD -h MYSQLSERVERNAME -e 'select * from foo...' database-name

Where,

-u : Specify mysql database user name
-p : Prompt for password
-e : Execute sql query
database : Specify database name
Examples

To list all database, enter:
$ mysql -u user -p -e 'show databases;'

To list count all rows, enter:
$ mysql -u user -p -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes' cbzquotes

Tell mysql to display output a page at a time, by using more or less pager:
$ mysql --pager=/usr/bin/less -u vivek -p -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes' cbzquotes

Redirect out to a file:
$ mysql -u user -p 'PassWord' -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes' cbzquotes > sql.output.txt

Comment: Hi Carol,syntax is fine but need to update which having special characters and with commit